# how yo resolve Mariadb conflict with mysql to install mySQL-python dependencies

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, centos, mariadb

I'm trying to install the required dependencies for MySQL-python but I'm doing

yum install mysql

and I'm getting this response

mariadb conflicts with MySQL51-server
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: package-cleanup --problems

I am a newbie on unix, I'm using a virtualenv on centOS 5.10. I'm setting up a Django project via SSH, but this is stopping me from it.

What do these suggestion mean? how should I proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you already have MariaDB installed, and it prevents installing MySQL. [MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL](https://mariadb.org/) and as such it should work with Django as is (excluding [some minor issues](https://code.djangoproject.com/search?q=MariaDB)).

You should be able to control the service using:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start

/etc/init.d/mysql status

/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Here is [more info regarding installation of MariaDB on CentOS](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2013/install-mariadb-on-fedora-centos-rhel/)

Comment: Thank you!  I just checked and I am able to start the service, I guess it will work with Django too.